# How to get the text of a text box from a word file from python

Tags: python

I would like your help to be able to access the text inside a Text Box element of a word .docx file. Currently, after doing some research, I found that the best way to do it is to access the element through the xpath, so to know what path it contains the text of a text box element I decided to convert my document to a .zip file to be able to access the structure, inside this I found a file in the path: /word/document.xml which contains this structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:document xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas"
    xmlns:cx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/chartex"
    xmlns:cx1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/9/8/chartex"
    xmlns:cx2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/10/21/chartex"
    xmlns:cx3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/9/chartex"
    xmlns:cx4="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/10/chartex"
    xmlns:cx5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/11/chartex"
    xmlns:cx6="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/12/chartex"
    xmlns:cx7="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/13/chartex"
    xmlns:cx8="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/14/chartex"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:aink="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/ink"
    xmlns:am3d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2017/model3d"
    xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
    xmlns:oel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2019/extlst"
    xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"
    xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math"
    xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
    xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing"
    xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing"
    xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word"
    xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
    xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml"
    xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml"
    xmlns:w16cex="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2018/wordml/cex"
    xmlns:w16cid="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2016/wordml/cid"
    xmlns:w16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2018/wordml"
    xmlns:w16sdtdh="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2020/wordml/sdtdatahash"
    xmlns:w16se="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2015/wordml/symex"
    xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup"
    xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk"
    xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml"
    xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape"
    mc:Ignorable="w14 w15 w16se w16cid w16 w16cex w16sdtdh wp14">
    <w:body>
        <w:p w14:paraId="390851B5" w14:textId="0F1265C2" w:rsidR="00D477FD"
            w:rsidRDefault="00A91CF5">
            <w:r>
                <w:rPr>
                    <w:noProof />
                </w:rPr>
                <mc:AlternateContent>
                    <mc:Choice Requires="wps">
                        <w:drawing>
                            <wp:anchor distT="0" distB="0" distL="114300" distR="114300"
                                simplePos="0" relativeHeight="251659264" behindDoc="0" locked="0"
                                layoutInCell="1" allowOverlap="1" wp14:anchorId="4FD68124"
                                wp14:editId="0D7E409D">
                                <wp:simplePos x="0" y="0" />
                                <wp:positionH relativeFrom="column">
                                    <wp:posOffset>34290</wp:posOffset>
                                </wp:positionH>
                                <wp:positionV relativeFrom="paragraph">
                                    <wp:posOffset>195580</wp:posOffset>
                                </wp:positionV>
                                <wp:extent cx="2190750" cy="2438400" />
                                <wp:effectExtent l="0" t="0" r="19050" b="19050" />
                                <wp:wrapNone />
                                <wp:docPr id="1" name="Cuadro de texto 1" />
                                <wp:cNvGraphicFramePr />
                                <a:graphic
                                    xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main">
                                    <a:graphicData
                                        uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape">
                                        <wps:wsp>
                                            <wps:cNvSpPr txBox="1" />
                                            <wps:spPr>
                                                <a:xfrm>
                                                    <a:off x="0" y="0" />
                                                    <a:ext cx="2190750" cy="2438400" />
                                                </a:xfrm>
                                                <a:prstGeom prst="rect">
                                                    <a:avLst />
                                                </a:prstGeom>
                                                <a:solidFill>
                                                    <a:schemeClr val="lt1" />
                                                </a:solidFill>
                                                <a:ln w="6350">
                                                    <a:solidFill>
                                                        <a:prstClr val="black" />
                                                    </a:solidFill>
                                                </a:ln>
                                            </wps:spPr>
                                            <wps:txbx>
                                                <w:txbxContent>
                                                    <w:p w14:paraId="563CE207" w14:textId="6341C126"
                                                        w:rsidR="00A91CF5" w:rsidRDefault="00A91CF5">
                                                        <w:r>
                                                            <w:t>Hola como estas</w:t>
                                                        </w:r>
                                                    </w:p>
                                                </w:txbxContent>
                                            </wps:txbx>
                                            <wps:bodyPr rot="0" spcFirstLastPara="0"
                                                vertOverflow="overflow" horzOverflow="overflow"
                                                vert="horz" wrap="square" lIns="91440" tIns="45720"
                                                rIns="91440" bIns="45720" numCol="1" spcCol="0"
                                                rtlCol="0" fromWordArt="0" anchor="t" anchorCtr="0"
                                                forceAA="0" compatLnSpc="1">
                                                <a:prstTxWarp prst="textNoShape">
                                                    <a:avLst />
                                                </a:prstTxWarp>
                                                <a:noAutofit />
                                            </wps:bodyPr>
                                        </wps:wsp>
                                    </a:graphicData>
                                </a:graphic>
                            </wp:anchor>
                        </w:drawing>
                    </mc:Choice>
                    <mc:Fallback>
                        <w:pict>
                            <v:shapetype w14:anchorId="4FD68124" id="_x0000_t202"
                                coordsize="21600,21600" o:spt="202" path="m,l,21600r21600,l21600,xe">
                                <v:stroke joinstyle="miter" />
                                <v:path gradientshapeok="t" o:connecttype="rect" />
                            </v:shapetype>
                            <v:shape id="Cuadro de texto 1" o:spid="_x0000_s1026"
                                type="#_x0000_t202"
                                style="position:absolute;margin-left:2.7pt;margin-top:15.4pt;width:172.5pt;height:192pt;z-index:251659264;visibility:visible;mso-wrap-style:square;mso-wrap-distance-left:9pt;mso-wrap-distance-top:0;mso-wrap-distance-right:9pt;mso-wrap-distance-bottom:0;mso-position-horizontal:absolute;mso-position-horizontal-relative:text;mso-position-vertical:absolute;mso-position-vertical-relative:text;v-text-anchor:top"
                                o:gfxdata="UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQC2gziS/gAAAOEBAAATAAAAW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbJSRQU7DMBBF&#xA;90jcwfIWJU67QAgl6YK0S0CoHGBkTxKLZGx5TGhvj5O2G0SRWNoz/78nu9wcxkFMGNg6quQqL6RA&#xA;0s5Y6ir5vt9lD1JwBDIwOMJKHpHlpr69KfdHjyxSmriSfYz+USnWPY7AufNIadK6MEJMx9ApD/oD&#xA;OlTrorhX2lFEilmcO2RdNtjC5xDF9pCuTyYBB5bi6bQ4syoJ3g9WQ0ymaiLzg5KdCXlKLjvcW893&#xA;SUOqXwnz5DrgnHtJTxOsQfEKIT7DmDSUCaxw7Rqn8787ZsmRM9e2VmPeBN4uqYvTtW7jvijg9N/y&#xA;JsXecLq0q+WD6m8AAAD//wMAUEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQA4/SH/1gAAAJQBAAALAAAAX3JlbHMvLnJl&#xA;bHOkkMFqwzAMhu+DvYPRfXGawxijTi+j0GvpHsDYimMaW0Yy2fr2M4PBMnrbUb/Q94l/f/hMi1qR&#xA;JVI2sOt6UJgd+ZiDgffL8ekFlFSbvV0oo4EbChzGx4f9GRdb25HMsYhqlCwG5lrLq9biZkxWOiqY&#xA;22YiTra2kYMu1l1tQD30/bPm3wwYN0x18gb45AdQl1tp5j/sFB2T0FQ7R0nTNEV3j6o9feQzro1i&#xA;OWA14Fm+Q8a1a8+Bvu/d/dMb2JY5uiPbhG/ktn4cqGU/er3pcvwCAAD//wMAUEsDBBQABgAIAAAA&#xA;IQBG9oAoNgIAAH0EAAAOAAAAZHJzL2Uyb0RvYy54bWysVEtv2zAMvg/YfxB0X+yk6cuIU2QpMgwo&#xA;2gLp0LMiS7EwWdQkJXb260cpzqPtTsMuMilSH8mPpCd3XaPJVjivwJR0OMgpEYZDpcy6pD9eFl9u&#xA;KPGBmYppMKKkO+Hp3fTzp0lrCzGCGnQlHEEQ44vWlrQOwRZZ5nktGuYHYIVBowTXsICqW2eVYy2i&#xA;Nzob5flV1oKrrAMuvMfb+72RThO+lIKHJym9CESXFHML6XTpXMUzm05YsXbM1or3abB/yKJhymDQ&#xA;I9Q9C4xsnPoA1SjuwIMMAw5NBlIqLlINWM0wf1fNsmZWpFqQHG+PNPn/B8sft0v77EjovkKHDYyE&#xA;tNYXHi9jPZ10TfxipgTtSOHuSJvoAuF4ORre5teXaOJoG40vbsZ5IjY7PbfOh28CGhKFkjrsS6KL&#xA;bR98wJDoenCJ0TxoVS2U1kmJsyDm2pEtwy7qkJLEF2+8tCFtSa8uMI8PCBH6+H6lGf8Zy3yLgJo2&#xA;eHkqPkqhW3U9IyuodkiUg/0MecsXCnEfmA/PzOHQIAG4COEJD6kBk4FeoqQG9/tv99Efe4lWSloc&#xA;wpL6XxvmBCX6u8Eu3w7H4zi1SRlfXo9QceeW1bnFbJo5IENDXDnLkxj9gz6I0kHzivsyi1HRxAzH&#xA;2CUNB3Ee9quB+8bFbJaccE4tCw9maXmEjuRGPl+6V+Zs38+Ao/AIh3Flxbu27n3jSwOzTQCpUs8j&#xA;wXtWe95xxlNb+n2MS3SuJ6/TX2P6BwAA//8DAFBLAwQUAAYACAAAACEASPXnCtsAAAAIAQAADwAA&#xA;AGRycy9kb3ducmV2LnhtbEyPwU7DMBBE70j8g7VI3KhdmqIQ4lSAChdOLYizG29ti9iObDcNf89y&#xA;guPOjGbftJvZD2zClF0MEpYLAQxDH7ULRsLH+8tNDSwXFbQaYkAJ35hh011etKrR8Rx2OO2LYVQS&#xA;cqMk2FLGhvPcW/QqL+KIgbxjTF4VOpPhOqkzlfuB3wpxx71ygT5YNeKzxf5rf/IStk/m3vS1SnZb&#xA;a+em+fP4Zl6lvL6aHx+AFZzLXxh+8QkdOmI6xFPQmQ0S1hUFJawEDSB7tRYkHCRUy6oG3rX8/4Du&#xA;BwAA//8DAFBLAQItABQABgAIAAAAIQC2gziS/gAAAOEBAAATAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABbQ29u&#xA;dGVudF9UeXBlc10ueG1sUEsBAi0AFAAGAAgAAAAhADj9If/WAAAAlAEAAAsAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA&#xA;LwEAAF9yZWxzLy5yZWxzUEsBAi0AFAAGAAgAAAAhAEb2gCg2AgAAfQQAAA4AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA&#xA;LgIAAGRycy9lMm9Eb2MueG1sUEsBAi0AFAAGAAgAAAAhAEj15wrbAAAACAEAAA8AAAAAAAAAAAAA&#xA;AAAAkAQAAGRycy9kb3ducmV2LnhtbFBLBQYAAAAABAAEAPMAAACYBQAAAAA=&#xA;"
                                fillcolor="white [3201]" strokeweight=".5pt">
                                <v:textbox>
                                    <w:txbxContent>
                                        <w:p w14:paraId="563CE207" w14:textId="6341C126"
                                            w:rsidR="00A91CF5" w:rsidRDefault="00A91CF5">
                                            <w:r>
                                                <w:t>Hola como estas</w:t>
                                            </w:r>
                                        </w:p>
                                    </w:txbxContent>
                                </v:textbox>
                            </v:shape>
                        </w:pict>
                    </mc:Fallback>
                </mc:AlternateContent>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
        <w:sectPr w:rsidR="00D477FD">
            <w:pgSz w:w="12240" w:h="15840" />
            <w:pgMar w:top="1417" w:right="1701" w:bottom="1417" w:left="1701" w:header="708"
                w:footer="708" w:gutter="0" />
            <w:cols w:space="708" />
            <w:docGrid w:linePitch="360" />
        </w:sectPr>
    </w:body>
</w:document>
```

The text that I want to obtain is inside: <w:t>Hello, how are you </w:t>, so to get there it occurred to me to enter noting the entire path until I reached it, having something like this at the end:

```
import docx

doc = docx.Document("documento.docx")
textbox_text = doc.element.xpath('/w:document/w:body/w:p/w:r/mc:AlternateContent/mc:Fallback/w:pick/v:shape/v:textbox/w:txbxContent/w:t')

print(textbox_text)
```

But it doesn't return the text, it doesn't return anything

Comment: In your code example, it looks like you have a typo in your `xpath` string, where you have `/w:pick`, it should be `/w:pict`.  Not sure that will fix the problem though.  Unfortunately python-docx doesn't have direct support for accessing TextBox elements https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/413

Comment: @nigh_anxiety, any alternative?

Comment: If you're only trying to pull data out of the document, and since you already have it as the XML, you could use `BeautifulSoup4` and the `lxml` to parse the XML directly.  If you're looking to modify the document it may be possible with those tools, but you have to have careful to not corrupt the XML - so maybe always save to a new file?